# Are there any proper ways of using/implementing "e.g." in a "Research Narrative"?

Tags: technical-writing, word-choice, software, business-writing

Are there any proper ways of using/implementing e.g. in a "Research Narrative"? I am working on a "Research Narrative" (I must write in both ALA and MLA format). I am curious about this e.g. but I rarely see it being used in "research reports" or something like that. Are there any examples to implement e.g.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two examples of how "e.g." has been used in scientific articles:

In the first passage the authors explain who they excluded from their study. "e.g." is used to give examples of medication.

> Exclusion criteria included psychiatric or neurological conditions that could be associated with secondary bruxism, use of medications that may have an effect on bruxism (e.g., muscle relaxants, neuroleptics, and SSRIs), alcohol consumption on a daily basis ... (Shochat et al., 2007).

In the second passage the authors give examples of publications validating the same claim. It is unnecessary to cite all the existing literature here, since it all says the same. A selection of examples is sufficient.

> This model comprised brain regions known as the “fear circuit” (e.g. Etkin, 2010; LeDoux, 2000; Marek et al., 2013), namely the amygdalar region, insula and the adjacent inferior frontal gyrus, in addition to the fusiform gyrus and superior temporal gyrus. (Brühla, Delsignorec, Komossac & Weidt, 2014)

As for writing in both MLA and APA format, I don't see how that is possible, since some of the style rules contradict and exlude each other. You can create two versions of the manuscript following each of the style guides.

---

Sources:

- Brühla, A. B., Delsignorec, A., Komossac, K., & Weidt, S. (2014). Neuroimaging in social anxiety disorder – A meta-analytic review resulting in a new neurofunctional model. *Neuroscience and Biobehavioral Reviews*, *47*, 260–280.
- Shochat, T., Gavish, A., Arons, E., Hadas, N., Molotsky, A., Lavie, P., & Oksenberg, A. (2007). Validation of the BiteStrip screener for sleep bruxism. *Oral Surgery, Oral Medicine, Oral Pathology, Oral Radiology, and Endodontology*, *104*(3), e32-e39.

Comment: Good Citations, Good sources, Perfected "Sources Cited List", No grammatical errors, and Decent word choice, however, I've found in line 1, sentence 1,paragraph 1, that this "I'm not really sure what you're asking, either" is fairly off-topic to me, as it shouldn't be in there. It should be in the comments area below my question or your answer. "I'm not really sure what you're asking, either", you have provided with me with the sources, thorough logic, and excellent explanation for what I was asking. I also think that if you have no idea of what I am asking, why answer my question?